# Request to keep an eye out for PROMYS admissions problems

Tags: discussion

Many of you may be familiar with [PROMYS](https://promys.org), a camp based out of Boston University which teaches number theory to high school students each summer. Students applying to the program are asked to submit their attempts at a problem sheet. The purpose of this is to see what ideas they come up with on their own, and they should not be asking for help on websites like this one. The due date for the application is March 15 2021, so the relevant timeframe is the next two weeks.

[Here](https://promys.org/sites/promys.org/files/assets/PROMYS%202021%20problems.pdf) are the problems.

This is a request to keep an eye out for these problems. If they show up, please flag them and please contact promys@bu.edu if you see them.

I originally posted this request at [math.meta.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33257/request-to-keep-an-eye-out-for-promys-admissions-problems?noredirect=1#comment150297_33257), and Gerry Myerson spotted that three of these problems had turned up on MO, so I am reposting here.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Can't you get the moderators to restore your old account?  Or is that just impossible (or something you don't want)?

Comment: @Lucia, probably possible, I do want it, but I don't want it enough to make the effort.

Comment: The Ross program (which is similar to promys and run through Ohio State) also has applications open until April 1st. However, I'm not sure how to screen for those questions, since it doesn't seem they are publicly available until you start the application.

Comment: #9 was on here and had at least two answers (mine was one of them), but it's gone now.  I'm disappointed to lose points from upvotes on my answer, but removing it is understandable.  Can the problem & answers be reinstated after the application deadline?